# Adding Typescript to Vue + Rails app - Imports no longer work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to add TypeScript to an existing VueJS + Rails app. I cloned this demo (https://github.com/gbarillot/rails-vue-demo-app) then followed the instructions from https://github.com/rails/webpacker

`$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install:vue`
`$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install:typescript`

I then modified `config/webpack/loaders/typescript.js` as described [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/typescript.md#typescript-with-vue-components).

Everything seems to compile, but when I go into my "home" view and change the `script` to typescript:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Layout from '../shared/layout';

export default {
  components: {
    Layout
  }
}
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/matt/projects/rails-vue-demo-app/app/javascript/packs/components/home/index.vue.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/matt/projects/rails-vue-demo-app/app/javascript/packs/components/home/index.vue.ts(13,20)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '../shared/layout'.
```

Why can I no longer find the layout file when typescript is enabled?

Comment: @AbM - That fixed it! If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember running into a similar problem for presentational components. Try adding an empty export in `shared/layout` so typescript can pick it up:

```
<script lang="ts">
  export default {}
</script>
```